# Text Wrangler Auto Wording Like Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver, textwrangler

I would like to know how in text wrangler how to get the auto wording like in dream weaver? Any idea how where you just type one letter in dreamweaver and choose words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press  Ctrl+Space it suggest html tag starting from entered first letter in html code view